# Similar beers to Hitachino Nest White Ale

Tags: recommendations

I have been drinking the Hitachino Nest White Ale for some time, but I find it quite hard to get in the UK.  I have been trying to find an alternative which is similar in taste.

It is similar to a Belgian Wheat Beer, but very light and citrusy. I like many Belgian Wheat Beers or Whit Beers like Blance de Namur, and more popular ones like Hoegaarden.  They are very nice, but I am looking for a more light and citrusy version similar to the Hitachino to try.

Does anyone have any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a tough question. Most of the witbiers I've had are locally distributed in the US, so you'll never find them in the UK.

Here are two lighter ones with a nice citrus kick that you might be able to get your hands on:

1. [St. Bernardus Blanche (Witbier)](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/st-bernardus-blanche-witbier/12269/)
2. [Ommegang Witte](http://www.ratebeer.com/beer/ommegang-witte/33198/)

Comment: Thanks I will check if our local world beer supplier can get these!